# how to access dialog fields in visual basic word macros

Tags: vba, ms-office, ms-word

I try to save a Word 2010 document to PDF and then want to do something with the file(name) that the user selected for this purpose in the corresponding dialog.
Also, I would like to make a few preconfigurations of dialog settings.
However, the following macro (in Microsoft Visual basic for Aplications 7.0, i.e. the stuff you get when simply recording and then modifying macros) does not work:

```
Sub MyMacro()
  dim retval as long
  dim DidTheExportToPdfActuallyTakePlaceSuccessfully as Boolean
  dim WhatWasThePdfFilenameTheUserChoseFinally as String

  With Dialogs(wdDialogExportAsFixedFormat)
    .ExportFormat = wdExportFormatPDF
    .OpenAfterExport = True
    .OptimizeFor = wdExportOptimizeForPrint
    .Range = wdExportAllDocument
    .Item = wdExportDocumentContent
    .IncludeDocProps = True
    .KeepIRM = True
    .CreateBookmarks = wdExportCreateNoBookmarks
    .DocStructureTags = True
    .BitmapMissingFonts = True
    .UseISO19005_1 = False

    retval = .Show()

    ' DidTheExportToPdfActuallyTakePlaceSuccessfully = ???
    ' WhatWasThePdfFilenameTheUserChoseFinally = ???
  end with
end sub
```

First of all, I get errors in all the lines `.ExportFormat` etc. 
It appears these problems  are caused by late binding.
To circumvent this problem I tried to add `option strict off` on top, but that immediately produces a compilation error ("Base or Compare or Explicit or Private expected").
I also read about reflection, but it seems that things necessary for that according to online findings (such as `dim x as System.Type` or `y.gettype()`) don't compile either ...

If I simply remove the offending lines, the dialog shows successfully and the pdf export takes places successfully. However, it seems that `retval` is always 0, no matter if the file is actually exported or the user hit cancel. Not to mention that extracting the actual pdf filename fails in the same way as does pre-filling the dialog options.

I'm a bit at a loss because all googling and searching through MS online help tends to take me only to *almost* compatible situations (especially, nothing found compiles, see above). What is the right way to achieve my goal?

Comment: You are dealing with several layers of Word History here. It may look to you as if the wdDialogExportAsFixedFormat dialog ought to have the properties you are trying to use (based on names within the dialog box, for example) but programmatic support for Word's builtin Dialog boxes was pretty arbitrary at the best of times. When Word's dialog box doesn't support what you want, you end up having to issue your own box, then issue the word command that actually does what you want.

Comment: Well, the ability to export to pdf is relatively new, so I would not have expected too much archeological dust above that :)

Comment: Yes, the history is that older dialogs tended to let you set useful properties using late-bound property names. Newer dialogs (since around Word 2000) tend not to. "Beware of geeks removing gifts" or some such.

Comment: So the simplest way forward is likely to be to use Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs) to prompt for the file name, code your own Userform to set/get any other options that you need, then call ExportAsFixedFormat to do the work.

Comment: @bibadia D'oh. Apparently there's a reason why new versions come with a documented "list of changes" and not a "list of improvements". For the site's sake I guess you should formulate your comments to an acceptable answer

Comment: >  a documented "list of changes" - as far as Word is concerned, that would be new :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Broadly speaking, only the older builtin dialogs in Word support "late bound" named parameters. Since around Word 2000, most (if not all) of them only recognise the early bound members of the Dialog class.

Possible workarounds include

- try to use Sendkeys (IMO always difficult to get right at the best of
  times)
- try to control the Dialog window via WIN32+Windows messages (no idea
  on feasibility there)
- adapt one of the standard Application FileDialogs as best you can (in
  this case, probably Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs) ),
  then follow up with your own UserDialog that prompts for any other
  options that you need, then call ExportAsFixedFormat to do the work.
- (+variations on (c), e.g. do some of it in .NET with a WIndows form)

Comment: I followed the third suggestion ultimately.